# RestTemplate & multipart/form-data response

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I need to write a REST Client using `RestTemplate` that will call the following endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{documentID}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "multipart/form-data")
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> getDocument(@PathVariable("documentID") long documentID);
```

This endpoint builds `multipart/form-data` response including a document (`InputStreamResource`) and the document's info (JSON) parts.
However, I receive the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap] and content type [multipart/form-data;boundary=f9yLuCpxZoS4W5lu5iYivlD8fIo28BBMr5PXzu;charset=UTF-8]
```

I have `FormHttpMessageConverter` (that is supposed to process form data to/from a `MultiValueMap`) in my `RestTemplate`, but it still doesn't work because according to the official docs this converter can't read multipart/form-data (only write):
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html

This endpoint works fine via Postman, returning both JSON and File parts, so I'm wondering which kind of magic I'm missing to make it work using `RestTemplate`.

Is it possible to write a REST client to process `multipart/form-data` response and if yes, which converter should be used for such messages, do I have to write a custom `HttpMessageConverter`?

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Do you have a solution already?

Comment: Nope. We went with a custom class that contains all the necessary data and wrote a custom HttpMessageConverter for it.

Answer (score 2):

I collided with the same case and wrote a simple example([MultipartMessageConverter](https://github.com/ozonophore/MultipartMessageConverter)). This example allows to convert a request(resource and JSON) to one DTO model as you can se in test. A model can consist Resource

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MultiPartMessageConverter(objectMapper));
        final ResponseEntity<ResultModel> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/test", ResultModel.class);
        final ResultModel resultModel = responseEntity.getBody();
        Assertions.assertNotNull(resultModel);
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, resultModel.secondModel.size());
        Assertions.assertEquals("Param1.Value", resultModel.firstModel.param1);
        Assertions.assertEquals("Param2.Value", resultModel.firstModel.param2);
```